# PHP Waterfall Chart or similar?

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a chart of PHP functions used when a page loads, and how long they took etc? Similar to a Waterfall chart in HTML showing which page elements were executed and when.

What I am trying to do is debug a page where some information is not being rendered despite the data being available. The inference being that the page has finished loading before all of the PHP has executed.

Comment: "page has finished loading before php has executed"? Not possible, since PHP would be the one GENERATING the page. a building does not magically complete its own construction when the contractor is in bed sleeping...

Comment: It would if the contractor employed subcontractors while he slept..

Comment: Karma comment - 5 years on and I understand more about PHP now. This was actually a development in Wordpress and in hindsight a plugin like WP Debug may have helped me determine which function was at fault. I should really have posted this question with a bit more detail on WPSE. Thanks for both responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Xdebug profiler (http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) for that.

https://blackfire.io/ is another similar tool.